# How can I make a texture flow along a bent mesh?

Tags: materials, node-editor, keyframes, texture-coordinates

My Goal is to create a texture that flows along a path.
An analogy would be like liquid flowing through a crazy straw.

As an example, I've created a `Texture Coordinate`. This links to a `Checker Texture` node. Then plugs into a `Material Output`

To animate the texture, I animate an `Empty` to move along it's Y axis. This `Empty` is linked to the `Object` selector in the `Texture Coordinate` node and the `Checker Texture`'s Vector input is hooked up to the Object output from the `Texture Coordinate` node.

[image: Node Setup]

This works pretty well on a stretched out cube:

[image: Long cube with armature & texture applied]

But fails when I bend that geometry. Technically, it's doing exactly what we might expect given the order of the nodes, but my goal is to have the pattern flow down the geometry and through deformations.

[image: Armature bent, texture unmoved]

The solution that comes to mind is to change the node order, but `Texture Coordinates` doesn't have an input.

I get this when I remove the `Texture Coordinate` node, but lose the ability to manipulate the texture position along the mesh:

[image: Armature bent, texture coordinates removed.]

If anyone can help me figure this out, I'd appreciate it.

*Note: controlling the texture with an `Empty` isn't a requirement. I just need something that can be key framed, such as a `Math` node.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: It looks like the problem has been fixed in the last version.

Old answer:

In 2.8 it looks like you need to mark seams and unwrap, then in the *Shader Editor* use the *Texture Coordinate UV* socket, play with the *Location* values of the *Mapping* node to make the texture move along the object. In the *UV Editor* you need to make sure that the UV is well placed if you want the texture to go in the right direction.

In 2.79 you can use the *Texture Coordinate* > *Generated* output socket instead of the *Object* output, then plug it into a *Mapping* node, play with the *Mapping* > *Scale* value to have the right proportion. Now with the *Mapping* > *Location* value you can make it move.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input -- I've followed your method and seem to have the same issue: https://i.imgur.com/S0JMiSk.mp4

Did I miss a step?

Edit: Got it working, just needed to UV unwrap.

Comment: you should not need to unwrap, but I've used 2.79, not 2.8, maybe I miss something, could you please share your object?

Comment: ok doesn't seem to work the same way in 2.8, you need to unwrap and use the Texture Coordinate UV socket

Comment: I can share my test file, but it looks like you reached the same conclusion I had. If you'd still like a copy, let me know. -- and thanks again, I spent way to long scratching my head on this one.

Comment: Yes same conclusion, it looks like the Generated output doesn't work the same way in 2.8   ;)